# re-sync a single large file using rsync

Tags: rsync

I have large disksafe file(71GB) created on R1soft server.I want to keep a copy of it to a remote backup server and syncing it when there's any change(after replication is complete). From what I understood, the rsync is the perfect tool to do this since it runs checksum across the entire file on both sides, comparing checksums for small segments of the file, and then only copy those blocks that do not match.

However, from my test, rsync make an entire copy of the file on the remote backup server after comparing the checksums. The delta changes in R1soft replication only has less than 1 GB daily, why rsync transfer the whole file instead of the changes to remote backup server?

In the disksafe directory, there's only one 71GB .db file. When running the rsync, it make another copy in the same directory. once rsync is done, the original file will be updated and keep only one in that directory.

-rw-------. 1 root root  71G Dec 10 17:38 b5c9b515-47f9-48a0-b6f6-062f13559dad.db

-rw-------. 1 root root  69G Dec 15 12:35 .b5c9b515-47f9-48a0-b6f6-062f13559dad.db.tc9w7A

Here's the rsync command I use:

```
rsync -avz --progress /disksafes/2abd4a9a-3a76-40fa-b034-afd29a49f3e3/ remote_server_ip:/disksafes/remote_backup/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `--inplace`

The --inplace argument instructs rsync *not* to upload the new file as a temporary file first.

This may be risky as a network problem // disconnect may put the dest file in a weird state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will do the test, but I am not very confident of the remote server network though.

Comment: After your test, please remember to "checkbox" this answer if it worked, or comment if it doesn't.